# What is the proper way of overriding equals and hashcode where either of two variables can be equal?

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

Lets say I have the following class

```
public class DualKey {
    int key1;
    int key2;
    // getters, setters and constructors go here
    public void equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null || ! obj instanceOf DualKey)
            return false;
        return this.key1 == obj.key1 || this.key1 == obj.key2 || this.key2 == obj.key1 || this.key2 == obj.key2;
    }

}
```

Is it possible to override hashcode in such a way that the equals and hashcode contract is preserved?

PS: I realize that it would probably be better to define a comparator instead, but I'm working with spark, where the only way to define equality is to override the equals method.

Comment: No, with your actual setup it is not possible (unless you just return `0` which will preserve the contract "if equal then hashcode has to be equal aswell" but you'd have tons of collisions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not possible, because that `equals()` implementation does not meet the Java API requirements:

> The equals method implements an equivalence relation on non-null object references:
>
> - It is *reflexive*: for any non-null reference value `x`, `x.equals(x)` should return `true`.
> - It is *symmetric*: for any non-null reference values `x` and `y`, `x.equals(y)` should return `true` if and only if `y.equals(x)` returns `true`.
> - It is *transitive*: for any non-null reference values `x`, `y`, and `z`, if `x.equals(y)` returns `true` and `y.equals(z)` returns `true`, then `x.equals(z)` should return `true`.
> - It is *consistent*: for any non-null reference values `x` and `y`, multiple invocations of `x.equals(y)` consistently return `true` or consistently return `false`, provided no information used in `equals` comparisons on the objects is modified.
> - For any non-null reference value `x`, `x.equals(null)` should return `false`.

Specifically, it is not transitive. With your definition, `(1,2) == (2,3)` and `(2,3) == (3,4)` but `(1,2) != (3,4)`.

This non-transitivity makes it impossible to implement a non-trivial hash code method. The only thing you can do is return the same number for every object. That'd be a valid implementation, though very poorly performing.